# How to get rid of the padding of SF Symbol in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

In example, I have a simple SwiftUI code that has an SF Symbol yet without any paddings. Here, I'm using .scaledToFit, so the image would be edge to edge (in future I'm gonna apply padding to it).

```swift
        VStack{
            Image(systemName: "drop")
                .resizable()
                .font(.largeTitle.weight(.ultraLight))
                .scaledToFit()
        }
```

Screenshot shows a small gap on the right side:

[image: Screenshot shows a small gap on the right side]

After using additional padding, the image still looks off. That gap becomes less but it's still noticable.

My expectation was that applying .scaledToFit would actually scale the image to fit the screen, and then I could use the padding.

Though even with padding the issue persists:

[image: Though even with padding the issue persists.]

I tried to use .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit), and also different aspect ratios hoping that it could fix it.

Also the same issue persists even using the "square" SF Symbol (that likely excludes aspect ratio issue cuz square is 1:1) Though I fixed issue with square using .imageScale(.large)

Square without .imageScale(.large):

[image: Square without .imageScale(.large)]

Square with .imageScale(.large):

[image: Square with .imageScale(.large)]

Comment: It happens that you've picked an SF symbol that does have a little white space on the right size. You can't magically get rid of it; it's part of the image. If you add a background to your image view, you can see that the image view itself is correctly positioned. I find experimentally that it's a bit better if you remove the `.font` modifier.

Comment: As matt said, the symbol itself has some right margin. If you download the SF Symbols app from https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/ you can export the symbol as a PNG and crop away the right-side margin yourself.

Comment: yes, matt is right. I added the background, and the SF Symbol definitely has a little space on the right.


@ClausJørgensen I am already using the SF Symbols app but I couldn't find how to export a .png from it.

Comment: @maxoliinyk right-click, copy image as. Then you can paste it into any folder you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when you use one of the named font sizes, there is sometimes a margin and sometimes not. But with some trial and error, a font size can usually be found which has no margin.

My guess is that all of the following factors can have an impact on the margin:

- the symbol being shown
- the font size
- the font weight
- the text size in the accessibility settings
- the screen size.

If you want to show a particular symbol with a particular font weight then it works best to use a `.system` font with a specific fixed size. This approach seems to be more resistant to different text size settings. However, finding the font size that works requires testing across different screen sizes. By using a process of binary chop, a size can usually be found quite quickly.

Testing with Xcode 15.2 on an iPhone 15 simulator and iOS 17.2, I found that the "drop" image works with a font size of 15 (corresponding to `.subheadline` at the default text size):

```swift
Image(systemName: "drop")
    .resizable()
    .font(.system(size: 15).weight(.ultraLight))
    .scaledToFit()
```

[image: Screenshot]

However, on an iPhone SE, you still see a margin. A size of 14.470234 works on the iPhone SE, but not on iPhone 15. So this one is difficult to get right across different devices.

For the "square" image, I found that a font size of 14.0534608 works on iPhone 15, iPhone SE and iPad 10 gen:

```swift
Image(systemName: "square")
    .resizable()
    .font(.system(size: 14.0534608).weight(.ultraLight))
    .scaledToFit()
```

[image: Screenshot]

I'm sure that there must be a way to calculate the font size from the screen size, but so far I haven't been able to work out the formula.

**Conclusions from all of this**

- It is usually possible to find a font size that works, but different symbols and different devices might require different values.
- Unless a formula can be found which allows the font size to be computed, there is a risk that these magic numbers will not work with new devices, or with a future iOS version, or if SF symbols are updated. Failure to work means a margin will be seen.
- If a margin would represent a serious issue, a safer approach would be to convert the symbols to a regular .png image. One way to do this would be to take a screen snapshot.

Comment: Weirdly, I have the same issue with padding on the right while using the same code as you. Could this be Xcode or Simulator bug?

Comment: I've tried in both preview and simulator. Sadly, I can't test the behaviour on a physical device. BTW, my simulator is on all default settings. Just tested it, and yes accessibility text size definitely affects it a little bit.

Comment: Yep, it definitely looks great now. I wonder if I should change the sizes depending on the device size. Anyway, it seems like a correct answer. Thanks

Comment: @maxoliinyk Thanks for accepting the answer. Alas, it doesn't seem to work reliably across different device sizes, I tried it on simulators for iPad and iPhone SE and neither looked right. So it must depend on the exact screen size. I'll keep experimenting in case there's a better way to fix.

Comment: @maxoliinyk Answer updated again to include notes about different screen sizes

Comment: great! you explained everything really well. Still, it seems to me that this exact behaviour is a bit weird, and probably should be fixed by Apple. IMO, that's not great that we have to play "hit or miss" to place a character... I might fill a feedback to them.